# How to get PHPMyAdmin to show MySQL warnings?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I use `PHPMyAdmi`n for convenience in updating a remote database.

But it doesn't show warnings, by default, which recently got me into some embarrassing trouble where I was updating a SET field with string not on its list and not noticing the problem.

I'm using `2.11.9.1 (Dreamhost's default install)`.

On the `PHPMyAdmin` wiki it lists "Display warnings" as a feature of [version 2.9.0](http://wiki.cihar.com/pma/phpMyAdmin_2.9.0-rc1) and even "Display all warnings" as a feature of 2.10.2 -- but how do I actually turn this on? The documentation isn't great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Dreamhost gives you access to the configuration file for their installation of phpMyAdmin.  However, you can easily make your own installation of phpMyAdmin by downloading the source from [their website](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and just untarring it to the directory you want to access it at (your-domain.com/phpma for example).  Then, follow the [website's instructions for editing your config file](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#quick_install) (which should include enabling warnings like you've asked).

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for the same thing.

When I ran `INSERTs` using the standard phpMyAdmin 'insert' form, rows would get inserted but a red bar would appear stating any warnings.  But when I did a *bulk insert*, no warnings would appear and a green bar appeared instead just saying the number of rows affected (giving you the impression that it had all gone successfully, when in fact it may not have).

I found I had to send the `SHOW WARNINGS` command manually.  For example, when running this query, I put both statements into the phpMyAdmin SQL box.

```
INSERT INTO test2 SELECT * FROM test1;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

This gave a list of warnings like the following...

```
Level    Code   Message
Warning  1265   Data truncated for column 'a' at row 1
Warning  1265   Data truncated for column 'a' at row 3
Warning  1265   Data truncated for column 'b' at row 3
Warning  1366   Incorrect integer value: 'x' for column 'b' at row...
```

***Things to note:***

- You cannot run the `SHOW WARNINGS` command later, it will appear empty.  It must be in the box with your initial query when you click "Go".  This is because MySQL only holds the warnings for the last query you ran.  Every time you click a link or button phpMyAdmin runs all sorts of other queries on the DB and so your previous warnings get lost.
- phpMyAdmin does *NOT* support showing multiple results from a custom query.  So doing this as one SQL script does *NOT* work... (as of version 3.4.10.1)

  ```
  INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ('my text', 'something else');
  SHOW WARNINGS;    # you won't see the warnings from here
  INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ('my text', 'something else');
  SHOW WARNINGS;
  ```

  Although the method above will not work in phpMyAdmin, it *SHOULD* work fine in the MySQL command line client.  So use that if you need to.

If you do have multiple inserts and want to show all warnings, you've got to chain them together as a single `INSERT` statement.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES 
('my text', 'something else'), 
('my text', 'something else');
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but if I remember correctly you need to have access to the phpMyAdmin config file to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

> follow the website's instructions for
>   editing your config file (which should
>   include enabling warnings like you've
>   asked).

Well yes, it should. But I don't see it in the config file and I don't see it in the page you linked to. I've already looked for information in the obvious places, believe me.